# Declaring length of tuple/list into a tuple

Tags: python-3.x

```
tup=(5,2)
s=tuple(len(tup))
```

**here I am facing a problem, please tell me why second statement is wrong in python**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial variable `tup` is already a `tuple`. Now, let's unpack the second line step by step:

1. The innermost statement is evaluated first, i.e `tup`, which is replaced by a reference to `(5,2)`.
2. Next, `len(tup)` ---> `len((5,2))` returns the number of elements in your `tup` tuple, which in this case is 2.
3. You then try to create a tuple by using the `tuple` constructor. Based on the steps above `tuple(len(tup))` ---> `tuple(len((5,2)))` ---> `tuple(2)`.

However, if we take a look at [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), we see that the `tuple` constructor takes an **iterable** as its argument. Here's the definition of an iterable in Python:

> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple) and some non-sequence types like dict, file objects, and objects of any classes you define with an **iter**() method or with a **getitem**() method that implements Sequence semantics.

When you try to run the second line of code, you will likely see an error that looks like this:

`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

What this is telling you is that `len(tup)` == 2 is not an iterable - it is an *integer* (int for short).  Since integers are not iterables in python, it does not satisfy the function contract for the `tuple` constructor, and your code fails.